# Validate symfony form without post

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I an using the symfony form to create a form and validate it. But i want to pre-validate the form on page loading itself ie. validate the form without post. Is it possible to do it in symfony?.

I have tried to use `$form1->isValid();` on the else part of post. But its not working.
Also I tried to use the `submit()`,

```
$data = $form1->getData();
$form1->submit($data);
$form1->isValid();
```

but with no success

*the form fields are dynamic and the validations are also dynamic. So a form that is preloaded can have error fields.

Comment: You already have some data set, ie. an Entity, and you want to edit it, is that right ?

Comment: You can't do that. Form validation checking by what you typed in the form fields. Page load can not imagine what you thinking for type a new data.

Comment: Plus, if the Entity comes from your DB, it should already be valid

Comment: you could have a route you post with ajax the form to, then it just checks if its valid in callback and then do the real submit action

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is for sure manual Entity Validation. I can imagine cases when you can't trust data already saved in database or, you want to pre-fill object with data from other source (external request response) before giving it for user to edit.

Please read docs about validation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Possible code:

```
$author = new Author();

// ... do something to the $author object

$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($author);
```

In this case you don't use constraints from FormType but validator constraints (they can be declared in entity - they will be used also by FormType): http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraints

Comment: If you validate the entity in this way, it's very difficult to map the violations to a form as the ViolationMapper expects PropertyPaths to be relative to "children" and this is not the case when you simply validate the entity.